# CSS - Gradient text-shadow

Tags: css, text

I want to make a gradient text-shadow (like this)
[image]
Is it possible to do that with CSS or/and Javascript?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it with a `linear gradient`, like in the example snippet below. Please note, that this does **not work** in *Internet Explorer* and *Edge*. I tested it successfully in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, and have no option to test it with Safari.

```css
 div {
    font-size: 128px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0000 5%, #00B053 15%, #1BAADA 30%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 12px transparent;
    color: #000; 
 }
```

```html
<div>
   Text
</div>
```